# MVC 4 - using two tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a new MVC4 application. At present I want to manage two tables, one named Branch and one named Business.

Business has two columns, ID and Name

Branch has three columns, ID, Name and Business ID.

Using a model for each branch.cs and business.cs, I am able to create controllers and views (using the EF) and amend the data records perfectly.

I would like to however, have a single page (view?) that allows me to enter a branch and select the business from a drop down, then populate the branch table with the ID in the BusinessID column.

I am struggling to get my head around this, the whole thing has been a learning curve and I am not articulating myself correctly in google!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to create a ViewModel, like `BranchForBusiness`:

```
public class BranchForBusiness
{
    public List<Business> Businesses { get; set; }

    public Branch Branch { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the controller you populate the `Businesses` and in the view you'll bind the `Businesses` to a `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Branch.BusinessID, ...)`, and create appropriate `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)` and so on.